# for-loop confusion

Tags: python

I'm supposed to write a code that will ask the user to input their names and the number of times they want it printed but I'm facing challenges. Kindly find my code below.

```
name = input('What is your name:\n ')
print('How many times do you want your name printed?')
answer = input(int())
for times in answer:
    print(name)
```

Comment: "I'm facing challenges" is not a problem statement. Please be much more specific when asking questions.

Answer (score 3):

The statement should be `int(input())` and not the reverse. The `int` function casts the input to expect an integer value so that mathematical operations can be performed. Hence we need to **convert** the `input()` to `int`
Also, `for i in answer` should be changed to `for i in range(answer)`
Thank you @AbhyudayVaish for reminding me.

Comment: And, what about `for times in answer`?

Answer (score 1):

The statement `answer = input(int())`, as mentioned above should be `answer = int(input())` instead.

Also, the statement `for times in answer` should be changed to `for times in range(answer)` as python would expect an iterable object after `in` (ie, an object over which python can iterate and get values). Here, `answer` will not be an iterable because it is an integer and not a list of objects that it can iterate over. `range(answer)` would tell python to iterate over the list of numbers starting from `0` to `answer-1` (and hence, the loop will be carried `answer` number of times, anyways).

Please note that **`for times in answer` will result in a `TypeError` due to the above mentioned reason.**

So your final code would be:

```py
name = input('What is your name:\n ')
print('How many times do you want your name printed?')
answer = int(input())
for times in range(answer):
    print(name)
```

Comment: Thanks, mate. It finally worked! Have a blessed and blissful day.

Comment: welcome! more than whether the 'code' works for you, i would be more delighted if you could understand the logic behind why it wasnt working before

Answer (score 0):

You forgot add range in you for loop, and you're writing "input(int)" it's wrong, because you just add 0 in your input, and then writing your name

```
name = input('What is your name:\n ')
print('How many times do you want your name printed?')
answer = int(input())
for times in range(answer):
print(name)
```